# App that shows Access point wireless security (Extended information for AP)

Tags: 11.10, wireless, network-manager

In 11.10, the default NetworkManager only shows the wireless access points but it does not provide a way to know if they are WEP, WPA, WPA2...

[image]

As you can see from the image all I can extract from each AP is the quality and if they have a type of security or not.

What graphical tool can I use to see all APs and what type of security they are using as well as any other common information provided by an AP like quality, signal level, etc...

Something similar to the terminal command "iwlist" but instead of terminal, a GUI app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternate to networkmanager is wicd, I use wicd in gentoo and it will show this type of information. It is in the Ubuntu repositories.

```
sudo apt-get install wicd-gtk
```

[image: wicd]

Comment: Much better than Wifi-Radar. Was trying it yesterday but this one is awesome. Thanks again bodhi.

Comment: @Luis Alvarado - Glad you like wicd